# Java: List not being sent over socket correctly?

Tags: java, list, sockets, object, client

I have another socket issue. This is actually rather strange compared to my other issues.  Ok so I have a client connected to a server which is sending data at a constant rate through an ObjectOutputStream and recieving data through an ObjectInputStream.  I have a list filled with Player objects which contain the players coordinates, game mode, etc.  When the client moves its player, the updated coordinates get sent to the server and that player's object in the list is updated.  Well, is supposed to be updated...  I print out the changed coordinates on the server side, but when I send the list to the player to print out, the coordinates haven't changed.  Here is the player class:

```
public static class Player implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8841477887428285969L;
    public int x, y, gamemode, ID;
    public String name;
    public Player(int x, int y, int gamemode, int ID, String name) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.gamemode = gamemode;
        this.ID = ID;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setPosition(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Where server recieves updated coordinates and prints the before and after out:

```
Package.Client_Server main_packet = (Package.Client_Server) obj;
System.out.println(S00.getPlayerByID(ID).x + ", " + S00.getPlayerByID(ID).y);
S00.getPlayerByID(ID).setPosition(main_packet.x, main_packet.y);
System.out.println(S00.getPlayerByID(ID).x + ", " + S00.getPlayerByID(ID).y);
```

And here is where the client prints out its own coordinates sent from the server.  **The problem is here...** The updated coordinates are not displayed here but are still the old coordinates.  Am I doing something wrong?  The List still only has one object in it so it isn't just creating more objects somewhere...

```
Package.Server_Client main_packet = (Package.Server_Client) obj;
ID = main_packet.client_ID;
C00.players = main_packet.players;
System.out.println(C00.players.get(ID).x + ", " + C00.players.get(ID).y);
System.out.println(main_packet.players.get(ID).x + ", " + main_packet.players.get(ID).y); 
//I tried printing the list directly from the package as well but it isn't updated either...
```

Heck, I'll even show the package sent from the server to the client that the list is held in:

```
public static class Server_Client implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5198487406288606819L;
    public int client_ID;
    public int online;
    public List<Player> players;
    public Server_Client(int client_ID, int online, List<Player> players) {
        this.client_ID = client_ID;
        this.online = online;
        this.players = players;
    }
}
```

My whole issue is that the updated coordinates are in the List of players on the server side but once the list is sent to the client, the updated data is no longer updated...  It is the same it was before the whole process started.  Is this a problem with how sockets work or am I just horribly stuck on a small error? The List can't be the problem because I exchanged it for an array of Player objects but it still wouldn't be read properly on the client side.  Help?

EDIT: This effect can also be seen because when another client connects to the server, client 1 cannot see client 2 because the list is not updated but client 2 can see client 1 as he was when he first connected to the server.  The console of client 1 always says he is the only player connected (list has 1 item in it) while console 2 always says there are 2 players connected (even if client 1 has disconnected).  Therefore, the list is not being updated.  So what could cause this?

And here is the method 'getPlayerByID(int ID)':

```
public static Package.Player getPlayerByID(int ID) {
    for(int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
        if(players.get(i).ID == ID) {
            return players.get(i);
        }
    }
    throw new NoSuchElementException("No player has the ID: " + ID);
}
```

Comment: What code would you like? I have plenty to show (although this is practically all the code I have related to this problem...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure if you are passing the same object reference to a single instance of `ObjectOutputStream` repeatatly that you are using [`ObjectOutputStream.writeUnshared(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeUnshared%28java.lang.Object%29) to do it OR calling [`ObjectOutputStream.reset()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#reset%28%29) between writes of that object.

If you fail to do this the `ObjectOutputStream` will see the object as already written and write a reference to the previously serialized form instead which will be the serialized state of the object the first time you wrote it.

Comment: Ok sorry if I sound ignorant or uneducated here but... what? This sounds like what could be causing the problem considering it will always send the same list somehow but how do I implement the fix?  (Sorry I am a relative new comer to coding) Do I just call .reset() on the output stream every time I send an object?

Comment: Oh wait! I got it! reset() did the trick.  Thanks a million!  Also, does calling reset() affect anything else besides that?  Just want to know in case I notice something else on the fritz later on

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `writeUnshared(Object)` instead of `writeObject(Object)` to achieve the same result.

Comment: @MrDoctorProfessorTyler Yes. When you send the first object over the output stream, it gets cached. If you then attempt to change the object and re-send the same object, the cache will not know that the object has changed and instead send the first object, because it is cached. It seems to be telling you that you should only be sending immutable objects down the pipe :) - you may take a performance hit if you let .reset() solve your problem.

Comment: Oh ok I get it.  That is a good thing to know. Thanks Alex and Dev!

Comment: .reset() worked for me, writeUnshared didn't seem to help. Been going crazy about this error, thanks !